# Наложение изображений и текста на картинку

Tags: java, android

Есть изображение заданного размера. Нужно с помощью приложения на android наложить на это изображение другую картинку меньшего размера и нанести текст. Какими способами это можно сделать?
Дополню: изображение не нужно выводить на экран, его нужно просто обработать. То есть загружаем изображение 1 и изображение 2 в приложение. На изображение 1 накладываем в определённое место изображение 2 и полученную в итоге картинку сохраняем. Вместо изображения 2 также планирую использовать текст.

Comment: Вам в сторону `RelativeLayout` или `FrameLayout` - это стандартный функционал - погуглите с ключевым словом *android+layout+overlay*

Comment: @Barmaley, я дополнил свой вопрос

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тогда вам надо использовать `Canvas` - *полотно*:

```
public static Bitmap overlayBitmapToCenter(Bitmap bitmap1, Bitmap bitmap2) {
    int bitmap1Width = bitmap1.getWidth();
    int bitmap1Height = bitmap1.getHeight();
    int bitmap2Width = bitmap2.getWidth();
    int bitmap2Height = bitmap2.getHeight();

    float marginLeft = (float) (bitmap1Width * 0.5 - bitmap2Width * 0.5);
    float marginTop = (float) (bitmap1Height * 0.5 - bitmap2Height * 0.5);

    //создаем пустой битмап с размерами как 1-й битмап
    Bitmap overlayBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap1Width, bitmap1Height, bitmap1.getConfig());
    //создаем canvas
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(overlayBitmap);
    //наносим на canvas 1-й битмап
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap1, new Matrix(), null);
    //сверху наносим 2-й битмап (по центру)
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap2, marginLeft, marginTop, null);
    //возвращаем итоговый битмап
    return overlayBitmap;
}
```

Вместо `drawBitmap()` можно использовать и другие примитивы, например `drawText()`